# CocoaPods - change name of generated Pods.xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, xcode5, cocoapods, xcode-project

#### Can I change the name?

[image]

CocoaPods generates a project automatically within my workspace.

Why i would want to change its name from `Pods` is a pretty lengthy story that I'll leave out.

Can I do it?  I couldn't see an answer in the Podfile documentation on cocoapods.org

#### Note:

I'm looking to change it in a way that would still allow me to re-run `pod install` in the future -- so simply changing the name of `Pods` within XCode will not work.